Как посчитать разницу во времени между городами на основе вводных данных времени?
Сутки 24 часа.
Имеем города Moscow, Yekaterinburg
Например, если в Екатеринбурге 01:00, то код должен вывести, в Москве 23:00.
Если вычислить 1 - 2, то получим -1, а не 23. Как написать правильно?
Попробовал написать код используя pytz, но не понимаю как дальше.
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

Moscow_tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Moscow')
Moscow_now = datetime.now(Moscow_tz)
Moscow_now_utc = Moscow_now.strftime('%z')

print('Europe/Moscow', f"{Moscow_now.strftime('%z')}")

Yekaterinburg_tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Yekaterinburg')
Yekaterinburg_now = datetime.now(Yekaterinburg_tz)
print('Asia/Yekaterinburg', f"{Yekaterinburg_now.strftime('%z')}")

Yekaterinburg_now_utc = Yekaterinburg_now.strftime('%z')

print(int(Moscow_now_utc))
print(int(Yekaterinburg_now_utc))

print(int(Moscow_now_utc) - int(Yekaterinburg_now_utc))


Лучше всё-таки через тайм-зоны нормально пересчитать. pytz что ли библиотека.

Что в текущем коде не устраивает? Формат вывода времени? Или вам не текущее время нужно, а какое-то другое перевести?

Нужно при вводе времени Екатеринбурга 01:00 ночи, получать время Москвы 23:00.

Чтобы метку времени перевести в другой часовой пояс используйте datetime.datetime.astimezone. Это единственный способ, который учитывает все тонкости связанные с летним временем, которое может по разному переключаться в разных поясах:
import datetime
import re
import sys
import zoneinfo

dt = ()
tm = ()
tzs = []

for a in sys.argv[1:]:
    m = re.match(r'^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)$', a)
    if m is not None:
        dt = tuple(map(int, m.group(1, 2, 3)))
        continue

    m = re.match(r'^(\d+):(\d+)$', a)
    if m is not None:
        tm = tuple(map(int, m.group(1, 2)))
        continue

    found = [z for z in zoneinfo.available_timezones() if a in z]
    if len(found) == 1:
        tzs.append(found[0])
    else:
        print(f'Ошибка: строка "{a}" часовые пояса "{found}".')
        exit(1)

tz1, tz2 = map(zoneinfo.ZoneInfo, tzs)

if len(dt) == 0:
    now = datetime.datetime.now(tz=tz1)
    dt = now.day, now.month, now.year

if len(tm) == 0:
    now = datetime.datetime.now(tz=tz1)
    tm = now.hour, now.minute

time1 = datetime.datetime(*dt[::-1], *tm, tzinfo=tz1)
time2 = time1.astimezone(tz=tz2)

delta = time1.utcoffset() - time2.utcoffset()

print(time1.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M'), time1.tzinfo)
print(time2.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M'), time2.tzinfo)
print('разница:', f'-{-delta}' if delta < datetime.timedelta() else delta)


$ python switch_tz.py 29.11.2011 01:20 Yek Mos
29.11.2011 01:20 Asia/Yekaterinburg
28.11.2011 23:20 Europe/Moscow
разница: 2:00:00

$ python switch_tz.py 01:20 Yek Mos
29.11.2024 01:20 Asia/Yekaterinburg
28.11.2024 23:20 Europe/Moscow
разница: 2:00:00

$ python switch_tz.py Yek Mos 
29.11.2024 23:18 Asia/Yekaterinburg
29.11.2024 21:18 Europe/Moscow
разница: 2:00:00

$ python switch_tz.py Yek Kol
29.11.2024 23:32 Asia/Yekaterinburg
30.11.2024 00:02 Asia/Kolkata
разница: -0:30:00

$ python switch_tz.py Yek Kath
29.11.2024 23:38 Asia/Yekaterinburg
30.11.2024 00:23 Asia/Kathmandu
разница: -0:45:00



А как в конце посчитать разницу во времени между Екатеринбургом и Москвой?

Добавил в ответ, хотя не понимаю как вы хотите это использовать. Эта разница может меняться в зависимости от даты.

Спасибо. Но я еще пока не понял поможет ли мне это. Я пишу программу помогалку для себя, которая будет считать разницу во времени между городами. Например мне нужно посчитать разницу во времени между Екатеринбургом и Москвой вчера, когда в Екатеринбурге было 15:00!
К примеру ввожу время в pyqt 15:00, на выходе получатся Москва - 13:00.

@Gold_boomber, погоняйте последний вариант.

Код конечной интересный, но очень хардкодный, попробую разобраться.

У меня ошибка, из-за чего?
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\test2.py", line 28, in 
tz1, tz2 = map(zoneinfo.ZoneInfo, tzs)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

@Gold_boomber, в командной строке надо указать ровно две таймзоны.

Давайте продолжим обсуждение в чате.

Сделал pip install tzdata. В коде заменил sys.argv[1:] на ['Yek', 'Mos'], код заработал. Спасибо @Stanislav Volodarskiy/

import pytz
import datetime

Moscow_tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Moscow')
Moscow_now = datetime.datetime.now(Moscow_tz)
Moscow_now_utc = Moscow_now.strftime('%z')
print(Moscow_now.time())
print('Europe/Moscow', f"{Moscow_now.strftime('%z')}")

Yekaterinburg_tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Yekaterinburg')
Yekaterinburg_now = datetime.datetime.now(Yekaterinburg_tz)
print(Yekaterinburg_now.time())
print('Asia/Yekaterinburg', f"{Yekaterinburg_now.strftime('%z')}")

Yekaterinburg_now_utc = Yekaterinburg_now.strftime('%z')

print(Moscow_now_utc)
print(Yekaterinburg_now_utc)
t = Yekaterinburg_now - datetime.timedelta(hours=2)
print(t.now())
t = Yekaterinburg_now.hour - Moscow_now.hour
print(t)


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

К сожалению ответ не тот, у вас в коде высчитывается разница в часовых поясах. Необходимо отобразить время по  Москве, зная время в Екатеринбурге.

t = Yekaterinburg_now - datetime.timedelta(hours=2)
Ну вот же

Если к примеру в Екатеринбурге сейчас, 15:00, как код выведет, что сейчас время в Москве 13:00?

Ну да, вычитаешь разницу в часах между поясами и все, только нужно использовать объекты той библиотеки, которую используешь для времени. Время - это не int, а datatime, причем специфичный для каждой библиотеки которую используешь. Этот вариант позволяет считать именно "часы", а не просто числа 2 или другие. В конце концов можно просто запустить этот код сейчас и проверить)

По моему в конце нужно сделать так, верно?
Moscow_time_result = Yekaterinburg_now.hour - t

Можно так, если вам просто нужно числовое значение часов в Москве из времени в Екатеринбурге. Мой вариант возвращает именно полное время в Мск

Спасибо, на пару шагов продвинулся, буду дальше думать.

Прибавлять два часа нельзя. Буде ломаться вблизи переключения летнего/зимнего времени. Да, в России сейчас не так, но, нет, не надо сажать баги в программу на будущее. Только .astimezone.

Получилось так:
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# текущая дата
Yekaterinburg_date_time = datetime.now()

# вычитание одного дня
Moscow_date_time = Yekaterinburg_date_time - timedelta(hours=2)

print(f"Текущее время в Екатеринбурге: {Yekaterinburg_date_time.strftime('%m-%d %H:%M')}")
print(f"Текущее время в Москве: {Moskow_date_time.strftime('%m-%d %H:%M')}")

вывод:
Текущее время в Екатеринбурге: 11-29 19:50

Текущее время в Москве: 11-29 17:50


Это не будет работать для других пар городов. Нужно учитывать летнее время. Разница между поясами не всегда одна и та же.

Да даже это перестанет работать после ближайшей реформы часовых поясов в РФ

Согласен, у меня ерунда получилась.
